# Dynamic WPF DatagridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid with two columns: CountryName and CityName. 
When a user selects a ContryName the CityName Combo that related to current row must be updated with country city names from Entity-FrameWork table. The user also can edits all rows that he was added previously.

What is the best solution to implement this in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Bound Datagrid to Observable Collection to reflect changes at runtime